# Query to transfer data from one database to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 database's and I need to transfer data from database 1 to database 2.

Only the data that in database 1 but not in database 2.

DB 1

```
----
MyTBL 1
-------
111
222
333
444
555
666
```

DB 2

```
----
MyTBL 2
-------
111
222
666
```

I need to transfer from 1 to 2.

It will looks like this:

DB 2

```
    ----
    MyTBL 2
    --------
    111
    222
    333
    444
    555
    666
```

I need SQL query, I work in SQL Server 2012

I tried a few things - but without success.

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 ?

Comment: "I tried a few things - but without success"  Where???  We don't see a single query posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing at your names:

```
INSERT DB2.dbo.MyTBL2
 (DataColumn)
SELECT DataColumn
 from DB1.dbo.MyTBL1
EXCEPT SELECT DataColumn
 from DB2.dbo.MyTBL2
```

`SELECT EXCEPT` can be very powerful. More info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

If both databases are on the same instance, merge is a reasonable solution for this. Assuming the schema for all objects is `dbo`, run the merge statement inside db2:

```
merge dbo.MyTBL2 t2
using db1.dbo.MyTbl1 t1 on t1.yourcolumn = t2.yourcolumn
when not matched then 
insert (yourcolumn) values (t1.yourcolumn);
```